# Sharing Private AMI: Not showing up on other account

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am trying to share an AMI (runs Windows Server 2008 R2) from one AWS account to another. I used [these instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/sharingamis-explicit.html) to share it from the Console. I shared it to the account ID found under `Account Id` in the `Account Settings` on the desired account to share it to. This then appears under `Modify Image Permissions.`

However, when I try to view the shared AMI from the second account, as [described here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/usingsharedamis-finding.html), no image appears. I have tried logging out and back in to the AWS account, but it still has not appeared.

Is there a step I'm missing? Is there a waiting period?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've done all the steps correctly, make sure you're in the correct region as AMI's are region specific.

Answer (score 0):

As Derek confirmed above first of all check you are in same region, secondly check you have selected private images available in AMI page.